# page-proofs changes with it's scale

Tags: html

I have a [demo-page of my site](http://xmpp1.feelinhome.ru/utilities.php)
When I change scale from 100% to 150 or to 50 or whatever, elements change it's positioning. Any advice how can I prevent this?
The biggest problem is with part

```
<form method='POST' action='/utilities.php'>Показания за период по <input name='demoCalendar' id='demoCalendar' type='text' class='dateInput'/><input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' value='Обновить'/></form>
```

if it is 150% elements are one under other. Any suggestions?
Also I couln't make fiddle of that because the problem is with whole site.
Example:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Screenshot of absolute positioning]

It's more of a problem with the web page in general, if the text can't fit the line then it has to wrap to the next line.

There is a possible solution to use absolute positioning to keep all the items in a stack but this would result in the text field and button overlapping the text on top like the screenshot shows.

If this is what you want though, you can see the necessary edits on the web inspector. Here is the raw output but you'll want to convert the `style` attributes to using CSS classes.

```
<div id="readings">
  <form method="POST" action="/utilities.php" style="position: relative; height: 40px; width: 100%;">
    <p style="position: absolute; left: 0;">Показания за период по</p>

    <input name="demoCalendar" id="demoCalendar" type="text" class="dateInput" style=" position: absolute; right: 100px;">

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Обновить" style=" position: absolute; right: 0;">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I've change it and look result now, the biggest probem is still actual.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is exactly, if I zoom to 150% all the elements still sit in a line. Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: Here is screenshot look at input and button. They are under text.

Comment: Is it possible to do something? May be I should change something in general?

Comment: I've updated my answer to show a possible absolute position approach

Answer (score 0):

I've added min-width to elements. 
like this:

```
div#readings
{
    background-color: #F4F4F1;
    width:110%;
    font-size: 20px;
    min-width: 550px;
}
```

Now elements don't wrap next line.